# HTTPS hostname from IP address

Tags: java, youtube, ip, host, hostname

I have been trying to get the hostname from IP address. It works fine as long as I provide http request. But, when I give a https IP address then it returns me the same IP Address instead of the name.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class IPTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {  
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String ipAddress = addr.getHostAddress();    
        System.out.println("IP address of localhost : " + ipAddress);
        String hostname = addr.getHostName();
        System.out.println("Name of hostname : " + hostname);


        //Youtube IP Address as it's using HTTPS
        InetAddress addr2 = InetAddress.getByName("92.226.0.76");
        String host = addr2.getHostName();
        System.out.println(host);
    }
}
```

Comment: that IP address belongs to Telefónica Germany GmbH, and on my system I get the output `x5ce2004c.dyn.telefonica.de`. What output are you getting and what do you expect to get?

Comment: You should not rely on reverse IP lookup, since multiple hosts may be served by a single IP address. *Reverse IP lookup is unreliable.*

Comment: I got the address while pinging youtube.com...